# Issue Related to Binding Image in <asp:Repeater> Control

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater

I have asp.net Web Application. i have following Repeater control on the .aspx Page:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="repHomeList" runat="server" onitemdatabound="repHomeList_ItemDataBound">
  <ItemTemplate>
    <div class="pro-col">
      <div class="p-img">
        <asp:Image runat="server" ID="imgHomeImage" />
        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblImageName" Visible="false" Text='<%#Eval("Images") %>'></asp:Label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

and Following Event

```
protected void repHomeList_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e) {
  if (e.Item.ItemType != ListItemType.Item && e.Item.ItemType != ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    return;
  Image imgHomeImage = (Image)e.Item.FindControl("imgHomeImage");
  Label lblImageName = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("lblImageName");
  if (imgHomeImage != null && lblImageName != null)
    imgHomeImage.ImageUrl = Server.MapPath("PropertyImages/" + lblImageName.Text);
}
```

the above code compiles fine. but Image is not displaying when DataBinds in Repeater Control.

so how to set Image on ItemDatabound event ??

Thanks

Comment: first check ur image `src` in html may be its bind diffrent path

Answer (score 0):

Try changing it to this instead:

```
imgHomeImage.ImageUrl = Server.MapPath("~/PropertyImages/" + lblImageName.Text);
```

Please note the `~`

Ps you can get the image name server side with the following:

```
ListViewDataItem dataItem = (ListViewDataItem)e.Item;
YourObject anObject = (YourObject)dataItem.DataItem; 
var images = anObject.Images;
imgHomeImage.ImageUrl = Server.MapPath("~/PropertyImages/" + images);
```

You'd have to change `YourObject` to your specific object.
This would avoid the need to write them out and retrieve them.

Comment: what could be YourObject ??

Comment: @ghanshyam.mirani The object that is in the collection that you have bound to the list view.